# Calling show() on list-item makes it a block element and makes bullet disappear

Tags: jquery

I am new to JQuery but I've started by making a list creator essentially. I have an empty list and an input field and a link for the user to add elements to the list. When I add something, I would like it to be hidden at first and then show up dynamically using JQuery. Currently, it adds it to the list but it sets the `display: block` instead of `display:list-item` or nothing at all. Am I doing something wrong?

So here is some code

```
$('a#addstep').click(function() {
    if ( $('#step').val().length > 0 ) {
        $('<li />')
            .text($('#step').val())
            .hide()
            .appendTo('ol#instructions')
            .show('normal');
    }
});
```

Here is some HTML

```
<ol id="instructions"></ol>
<input type="text" id="step" size="60" />
<a href="#" id="addstep">Add</a>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure why your adding the extra calls to show/hide.  When you add an item it will show it.   Please explain further as to why you need to do the show/hide.

If you absolutely have to.

```
$('a#addstep').click(function() {    
    if ( $('#step').val().length > 0 ) {        
        $('<li />')            
        .text($('#step').val())            
        .hide()            
        .appendTo('ol#instructions')            
        .show('normal', function() {
            $(this).css('display', 'list-item')
        });    
    }
});
```

Comment: I don't absolutely have to but the point of using JQuery is partially to make things look more visually appealing. The fades help.

Comment: That sort of does the trick. I'll probably see if I can get it to display as a list-item before calling show() so it's in the proper order. Thanks!

Comment: Maybe I was misunderstanding the use of show(). It seems that fadeIn() does the same thing without undesirable results.

Answer (score 0):

try using

> (".theclass").css("display", "inline {or your desired value}");

instead of show('normal')

Answer (score 0):

Try this (untested):

```
$('a#addstep').click(function() {
    if ( $('#step').val().length > 0 ) {
        $('<li />')
            .css('display', 'list-item')   // ADDED
            .text($('#step').val())
            .hide()
            .appendTo('ol#instructions')
            .show('normal');
    }
});
```